# Find a set of words near each other in a text, in any order

Tags: regex, dart, full-text-search

To highlight the result of a full-text search of multiple words, I tried to used regex to find items with a predefined distance, using the following regex, (distance between two words is up to 100 characters):

```
word1(?:\\s|.){1,100}?word2
```

This will find `word1 ... word2`, but will not find `word2...word1`
I know I can combine two regex phrases, but what if a user searches for say 6 words?

Comment: For two words, try `\bword1\b.{1,100}\bword2\b|\bword2\b.{1,100}\bword1\b`, `|` meaning logical "or". As you just want to validate that the words are sufficiently close to one another you don't need anything to be non-greedy. Please define what your mean by more than two words being within a certain distance from one another. Might the words be repeated?

Comment: The reason I asked you to define what your mean by more than two words being within a certain distance from one another is that there are at least two interpretations. One is that (for a distance of 100, say) there are no more than 100 characters between each pair of word. Another is that there exists a substring of no more than 102 characters that contains all the words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Objective**

Suppose we have the string:

```
Little Miss Muffet she sat on her tuffet, eating her curds and whey. Along came a spider who sat down beside her and frightened Miss Muffet away.
```

Now suppose we wish to determine if there exists a substring of no more than 70 characters that contains all the words `she`, `tuffet`, `her` and `spider`.

**First regex**

We can do that in two steps. The first is to match the string with the following regular expression.

```
(?!(?=.*(?:^| )she\b)(?=.*(?:^| )tuffet\b)(?=.*(?:^| )her\b)(?=.*(?:^| )spider\b)).*
```

This matches the string

```
she sat on her tuffet, eating her curds and whey. Along came a spider who sat down beside her and frightened Miss Muffet away.
```

which is the *shortest tail* of the original string that contains all four specified words.

[Regex 1](https://regex101.com/r/XGQEmU/7)

The regex engine performs the following operations

```
(?!                     : begin a negative lookahead
  (?=                   : begin a positive lookahead
    .*                  : match 0+ characters
    (?:^| )             : match the beginning of the string or a space
    she                 : match 'she'
    \b                  : assert a word boundary
  )                     : end positive lookahead
  (?=.*(?:^| )tuffet\b) : same as above for 'tuffet'
  (?=.*(?:^| )her\b)    : same as above for 'her'
  (?=.*(?:^| )spider\b) : same as above for 'spider'
)                       : end negative lookahead
.*                      : match remainder of string
```

**Second regex**

We may now use the following regular expression to attempt to verify that all four specified words fall within 70 characters of the beginning of the tail string matched by regex 1.

```
^(?=.{0,67}\bshe\b)(?=.{0,64}\btuffet\b)(?=.{0,67}\bher\b)(?=.{0,64}\bspider\b)
```

[Regex 2](https://regex101.com/r/XGQEmU/2)

The link shows two examples. The first is for the tail string matched by regex 1. That string is matched, meaning that all four specified words fall within the first 70 characters of the string. The second example is the same
as the first except I've inserted the word " big" before " spider". This has the effect of pushing the end of "spider" beyond the first 70 characters of the string, so there is no match.

Here the regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^                     : assert beginning of string
(?=                   : begin positive lookahead
  .{0,67}             : match 0-67 characters
  \bshe\b             : match 'she' with word boundaries
)                     : end positive lookahead
(?=.{0,64}\btuffet\b) : same for 'tuffet' except 64 rather than 67
(?=.{0,67}\bher\b)    : same for 'her' 
(?=.{0,64}\bspider\b) : same for 'tuffet' except 64 rather than 67
```

Answer (score 3):

I would probably not try to do this with a RegExp.

if you want to find *two* occurrences of *n* words within a short distance, then it's still doable. Something like:

```dart
var re = RegExp(r"\b(word1|...|wordn)\b[^]{1,100}\b(?:word1|...|wordn)\b(?<!\b\1)");
```

This should find any of word1 through wordn, followed by 1-100 other characters, and then followed by another of word1 through wordn (but not the same one because of the negative look-behind).

If you want to find *all* the words, in any order, then it's a very non-regular problem which regular expressions are really unsuited for.
You can generalize the expression above to something like:

```dart
RegExp(r"\b(word1|...|word10)\b"
  r"[^]{1,100}\b(word1|...|word10)\b(?<!\b\1)")
  r"[^]{1,100}\b(word1|...|word10)\b(?<!\b(?:\1|\2))"
  ...
  r"[^]{1,100}\b(word1|...|word10)\b(?<!\b(?:\1|\2|\3|\4|...|\9))");
```

That is probably not going to be particularly efficient with all those negative look-behinds, but the biggest issue is that it grows quadratically in the number of words.

So, what I'd do instead is:

```dart
List<Match>? findWords(String source, List<String> words) {
 var re = RegExp("\\b(?:${words.join("|")})\\b");
 var seenWords = <String>{};
 var matches = <Match>[];
 for (var m in re.allMatches(source)) {
   var str = m[0];
   if (seenWords.add(str)) {
     matches.add(m);
     if (matches.length == words.length) return matches;
   }
 }
 return null;
}
```

This will return a `Match` for each word in the `words` argument, if it finds all of them, and `null` if it does not.